# Netherlands - language requirements for 'highly skilled migrant' visa applicant's family (3rd countries)

Tags: working-visas, netherlands, family

I have a very hard time finding accurate info about this.

If a Rotterdam company is willing to sponsor me (a non-EU/Turkey country national) for a highly skilled migrant visa and I would bring my wife with me (same nationality), does **my wife** need to pass the so called 'Basic Civic Integration Examination' which also includes A1 Dutch language exam in order to come with me?

I will post the answer myself if I manage to find an accurate source in the meantime.

PS. I do know this is not the case with EU blue card but this type of visa is rarely issued in the Netherlands.

Edit: I do have some info from some friends there and sites like iamasterdam.com that there is no requirement but no official sources like ind.nl or actual immigration law.

Edit 2: Unofficial sites saying that it's not required for highly skilled migrants or their family:

- [iamsterdam.com](https://www.iamsterdam.com/en/living/feel-at-home-in-amsterdam/civic-integration)
- [mynta.nl](https://www.mynta.nl/en/knowledge-base/integration-and-permanent-residence-dutch-citizenship)
- [iamexpat.nl](https://www.iamexpat.nl/expat-info/dutch-expat-news/dutch-civic-integration-exam-what-expats-need-know)

I couldn't confirm this through official links but the user Relaxed found the laws:
[Civic integration decision](https://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0020674/2020-10-01#Hoofdstuk1) and [Civic Integration Act](https://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0020611/2021-01-01). I couldn't translate the legalese to the extent of fully understanding them though.

In the meantime, I found out that highly skilled migrant visa is classified as a 'temporary visa' for a 'non-temporary purpose'.

Comment: Which page in iamasterdam.com arre you thinking about? Are your friends from Turkey? They might qualify for one of the exemptions (some nationalities, transfering from another EU country, partner born in the Netherlands) without realising it's an exception and not the rule.

Comment: Relevant links: https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/immigratie-naar-nederland/vraag-en-antwoord/moet-ik-al-met-mijn-inburgering-beginnen-in-het-land-van-herkomst and https://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0020674/2020-10-01#Hoofdstuk1